# How to recognize how to run script?

Tags: bash

i'm trying write easy script in bash. I'd like to this script recognizes how to it has launched, command line or by another script. It is possible?

Comment: You can try to *infer` from `ps -p ${PPID}`, but I don't know if/how you're going to know unambiguously.

Answer (score 1):

like r2evans said `${PPID}` is the right direction:

that is what you want:

```
echo "i was called from: $(ps -p $PPID -o command | sed '1d')"
```

see `man ps`, `man sed` and `man bash` for explanations. The PPID is explained in `man bash`.

If I call my script from the `testparent` script, it looks like this:

```
$ ./testparent arg1 arg2
i was called from: /bin/bash ./testparent arg1 arg2
```